# Solving Integrals w/Trig

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I need to solve the following integral:

$$\int \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) dx$$

This problem belongs to math notes that can be found [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralsWithTrig.aspx).

Here are the steps listed to solve the equation.
I can solve to a certain point but get stuck at $\text{step c}$.
$$\begin{array}{llr}
 &\int \frac 1 2 (1-\cos(2x))\cdot\frac 1 2(1 + \cos(2x))\,\mathrm dx&\quad\text{step a}\\
=&\frac 1 4\int 1 - \cos^2(2x)\,\mathrm dx&\text{step b}\\
=&\frac 1 4\int1 - \frac 1 2(1 + \cos(4x)\,\mathrm dx&\text{step c}\\
=&\frac1 4\int\frac1 2 - \frac 1 2\cos(4x)\,\mathrm dx&\text{step d}\\
=&\frac 1 4\left(\frac 1 2x - \frac 1 8\sin(4x)\right) + \color{gray}{\text{constant}}&\text{step e}\\
=&\frac 1 8x - \frac 1 {32}\sin(4x) + \color{gray}{\text{constant}}&\text{step f}\end{array}$$

Why is $\cos^2(2x)$ from $\text{step b}$ equal to $\frac 1 2(1 + \cos(4x))$ in $\text{step c}$?

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the readability, please ensure that I didn't change the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply a [trigonometric identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula):

$$\cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1 + \cos(2\theta)}{2}$$

where $\theta = 2x$ in your case.

Comment: Thanks Null...I of course had not yet considered substituting $\theta$ for 2x. After substituting $\theta$ for 2x the $cos^2(2x)$ can be replaced by the half angle identity you posted above...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Null answer, you can use this website to check out more trig. identities! I find this website: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html very useful ;)

Good luck!